# Javascript generate file and ask user to save it, possible?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple function that will generate a file from Javascript and then ask the user to save it on their computer somewhere.

First off is that possible using just JavaScript?

Second if so do you have a tutorial page that explains how

Second if not, do you know of the best way to go around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file) The file known as FileSaver.js works fine :)

Cheers Robert Harvey